# Open terminal and run command through python script

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, ubuntu-14.04

I just started with Python and I do not have experience with any other programming language as well. Thanks in advance for helping me.

I am looking to open terminal and run a command like "ls -a" and show the output in terminal, with the help of python script which I am running in IDLE. I have tried couple of options in them the command is running but I am not able to see the output.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

To literally do as you ask, use subprocess.Popen to open a shell and run a command.  Here is the equivalent for Windows, with two options that do the same thing.

```
import subprocess as sub

sub.Popen('cmd /K dir')
sub.Popen(['cmd', '/K', 'dir'])
```

I believe the list form works better for *nix. 'cmd' would be 'sh' or whatever for you.  '/K' means 'run the following command and *stay open for viewing*.

However, it is not clear why you want output in a new shell window rather than the window Python is already running in.  Also note that Idle is generally meant for developing programs rather than running them.

If you edited your question to show what you tried and explain what happened and why the result was not satisfactory, you might get a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
for arg in args:
pro = subprocess.Popen(['new_shell', arg],
                       stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
inpt = <script_to_be_run_in_shell> + <arguments> +'\n'
out, err = pro.communicate(inpt.encode())
```

Comment: Hi :), could you add a little introduction to your answer.